# why do I get null object in Spring by posting it and sending to another page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am playing with submitting Spring forms and now I have a problem with object. It's null. I don't know why. I decided to System.out.println this object and I get all the data but after sending it to another page it's null. How to fix this problem?

**Controller**

```
package com.megaproject3.MainProject.Controller;

import com.megaproject3.MainProject.Model.Book;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class BookController
{
    @GetMapping("/books/add")
    public String addBook(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("newAddedBook", new Book());
        return "addNewBook";
    }

    @PostMapping("/books/view")
    public String wwnewBook(@ModelAttribute Book book)
    {
        System.out.println(book.getAuthor() + " || " + book.getTitle()); // IT WORKS - I GET DATA I TYPE
        return "result";
    }
}
```

**addNewBook.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Add New Book</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/books/view}" th:object="${newAddedBook}" method="post">
    <p>Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/></p>
    <p>Author: <input type="text" th:field="*{author}"/></p>
    <p>Genre: <input type="text" th:field="*{genre}"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2 th:text=" 'You have just added ' + ${newAddedBook}"></h2> // You have just added null

<a href="/books/add">Add another one book</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is because your `wwnewBook` post url is different than the `addBook` get url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not binding the obtained data for result page.
Just simply bind it. The `@ModelAttribute` just gets the data from the page to be used in the `wwnewbook` method. It will not get binded by itself for the result page. Do Like this

```
@PostMapping("/books/view")
public String wwnewBook(@ModelAttribute Book book, Model model)
{
model.addAttribute("newAddedBook", book);
    System.out.println(book.getAuthor() + " || " + book.getTitle()); //     IT WORKS - I GET DATA I TYPE
    return "result";
}
```